# Boolean version of `\str_if_in:nnTF` — expl3

Tags: expl3, latex3

How can I use `\str_if_in:nnTF` as a boolean function i.e without `TF` arguments so that I could use it inside

```
\bool_lazy_and:nnTF
      { \str_if_in:nn {abc} {a} }
      { ... }
      {
        true code
      }{
        false code
      }
```

Comment: `\str_if_in:nnTF` cannot be fully expandable, so it cannot have a predicate form.

Comment: Use the nnTF one, set a temp variable like `tmp1` (name for illustration only), then check bool value of tmp1.

Comment: You may have a look at `functional` package. There any predicate function is protected. Therefore you have `\StrIfIn` as well as `\StrIfInTF`.

Comment: @L.J.R. as egreg said for such a boolean test you need an *expandable* test.  Making everything protected in functional breaks such use cases.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This is just my opinion: for programming it is a better choice to make all functions protected and only variables can be expandable. Could you provide an example where `\StrIfIn` breaks?

Comment: @L.J.R. then you should perhaps not claim that functional is an interface to expl3 as many functions there are expandable by design. E.g. \fp_eval or the text functions.  If you want examples: search for `expandable` on this site.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I think an interface can be some tool to produce the same result, but maybe in a different way. Like TikzEdt is an interface to tikz, but you could draw tikz graphics with mouse.

Comment: @L.J.R. it doesn't produce the same results. I can easily use `\num{\fp_eval:n{15*1.19}}` but if I replace that by `\FpEval` it explodes. You are not building an interface to expl3, you are building your own system with quite different design choices. And personally I'm quite unhappy that you are using our names for this. If we want to make some of our functions more public we will have to break your package as the functions are not compatible.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry, I can not agree with you. Can we talk about this in https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/769 ? Or in https://github.com/lvjr/functional/discussions ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `etl` package, which defines a fully expandable form of `\tl_if_in:nnTF` (named `\etl_if_in:nnTF`). Please note that the functions of `etl` are slower than the `expl3` equivalents, so you should only use this if you have to be expandable.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etl}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \etl_if_in:nnTF { oo }
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \antshar_str_if_in:nn #1#2 {p, TF, T, F}
  {
    \etl_if_in:ooTF { \tl_to_str:n {#1} } { \tl_to_str:n {#2} }
      \prg_return_true:
      \prg_return_false:
  }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \antshartest { m m }
  {
    \bool_lazy_and:nnTF
      { !\tl_if_empty_p:n {#1} }
      { \antshar_str_if_in_p:nn {#1} {#2} }
      { true }
      { false }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\antshartest{}{abc}

\antshartest{def{abc}def}{abc}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The reason I wanted the predicate dorm is to make my code simpler and shorter, avoiding creating extra functions or temporary variables. But this approach doesn't seem to be any better at this. Anyway it might be helpful for someone else, so thank you for the answer.

Comment: @antshar well you didn't state your use case :) But in that case I'd stick with [user202729's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/643901/boolean-version-of-str-if-innntf-expl3/643952?noredirect=1#comment1604656_643901).

Comment: @antshar "Avoiding temporary variable to make code simpler" is exactly what latex3 does not do (because not everything are expandable) (for unexpandable things at least) -- it can't be done without "interpreting" another mini-language like how functional does.

Comment: Isn't it simpler to just use the `_p` variant of `etl_if_in` instead of defining a new one?

Comment: @user202729 not if you want string comparison, for that you need to stringify the input, so you're either using `\etl_if_in_p:oo { \tl_to_str:n {#1} } { \tl_to_str:n {#2} }` in every usage or define a new conditional which does that for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative solution with [`functional`](https://ctan.org/pkg/functional) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{functional}
\begin{document}

\IgnoreSpacesOn
\boolVarAndTF {\strIfIn {abc} {a}} {\intCompare {1} < {2}} {
  \prgReturn{True}
} {
  \prgReturn{False}
}
\IgnoreSpacesOff

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I saw your comment, but wanted to stick with pure latex3